# how to put array elements on a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I've been trying to put the value of my array in my table view cells, it's multidimensional array how should i do it?

here's a parser class

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"subsidiary"])
{
      NSLog(@"%i", [app.infoarray count]);
    [app.listArray addObject:app.infoarray];
    [app.infoarray removeAllObjects];

}
else
{
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"countryname"])
     {
         temp = currentElementValue;

     }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"name"])
    {

        theList.name = currentElementValue;
        [app.infoarray addObject:theList.name];
    }
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"address"])
    {
        theList.address = currentElementValue;
        [app.infoarray addObject:theList.address];
    }
```

the code below is the mainviewcontroller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

theList.countryname = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:0];
cell.textLabel.text= theList.countryname; ////<<WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;

}
```

I just want the cell.textlabel to display the country name
I'm just new in objective-c i hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    theList.countryname = [app.listArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text= theList.countryname;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;

    }
```

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano:Did you use tableview delegate?
NSlog(@"%@",[theList.countryname]);

Comment: it's null, there's no value in theList.countryname. what should i do?

Comment: @Tbt-lionArmanCapistrano:you are not storing country name in array

Answer (score 1):

This line makes issue:

```
theList.countryname = [app.listArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

Change it to:

```
theList.countryname = [[app.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtindex:0];
```

Comment: I got an error :( "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71854a0'"